# Percy Visual Regression Testing - First Run

Tags: testing, automated-tests, storybook, visual-testing

Trying to find out what exactly happens the first time Percy is run against Storybook. I've looked through the docs and can't spot a 'clear' answer. Is it:

1. Current state is taken as the default baseline for images without human intervention
2. A human is required to 'approve' the current state for each image
3. Depends - you can control Percy so it can be either 1 or 2 (link to the docs would be great)
4. Something else

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to someone at Percy the answer is:

1 - Current state is taken as the default baseline for images without human intervention